# How do I upload file via php with jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload

I present a dialog with a form to upload a file.

When OK is clicked, the selected file should upload.

How do I do this with jquery and PHP?

Code:

```
    if(act=='exchangePic')
{               
    $("#dialog").attr('title','Change picture ').dialog({buttons:{'ok':{class:'btn',text:'Ok',click:function(){
    $('#imgHolder_'+picture_id).css({'background-color':''});
    $(this).dialog('close');    

    }}}, show:'fade',hide:'explode',width:'380px',modal:true,closeText:' X  '}).html("<form><input type='file' id='newUpload' name='newUpload' class='upfile'/></form>");

}//end of act=='exchangePic'
```

Comment: You cannot upload files using XMLHttpRequest (AJAX). Try to use http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: @Arunkumar — You can. You just need a browser that supports the File API. Such: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications#Example.3A_Uploading_a_user-selected_file

Comment: @Arunkumar, XMLHttpRequest v 2.0 is able to handle files. You could also use jQuery form plugin if you want. It's really simple. http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why write everything yourself? [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) is a solid [open source uploader](https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload) with lots of great features.

Here is the [jquery sample](http://www.plupload.com/example_queuewidget.php)

[image: Plupload features]

Comment: Thanks Looks so nice! I'll try it now.